# AppleTV remote lost, can't use remote app

Tags: iphone, remote-control, appletv

I lost my AppleTV 4th Gen remote, so I tried to use the remote app on my iPhone but it's asking me to enter a code on the AppleTV! If I had a way to do that why would I use the remote app on the phone?

Is there anything I can do to fix/bypass this? *Replacement remotes are more expensive than the device itself.*

Comment: Your supposed to enter the code from your iPhone.

Comment: Without the AppleTV app on my iPhone, it's asking to enter the code on the AppleTV not on my phone. If I download the AppleTV app, it doesn't ask to enter a code but it's stuck at "connecting"!

Comment: Yes. Apple's instructions aren't what I'm experiencing. This is what the [app](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/SiFV9bTQ1XM) looks like on my iPhone.

Comment: You don't need to download the Apple TV Remote app on your iPhone. It should already be there as described in [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201664). What is your iPhone model and which iOS do you have installed on it? What exactly happens (or does not happen) when you follow the instructions on that Apple support page?

Answer (score 1):

The current apple tv remotes are quite expensive but any of the previous generation remotes will work.

Any chance you have any of the old white plastic or aluminum remotes that came with earlier generation AppleTV or iMacs.  Or buy for under $10 (ebay or maybe Craigslist)

[image: Old Apple Rmote]

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggested solutions resolved my issue.

I had to buy a universal remote from amazon and I'm able to control the AppleTV. It is pricey but cheaper than the new or used original Apple ones.

Comment: While this is a solution that worked for you, it doesn't answer the actual question of fixing/bypassing the need to enter a code into the AppleTV.

Comment: Good luck finding one.